# R and Access: Memory allocation error from relatively small table

Tags: r, ms-access

I have two tables in an Access database (called State) that I'm trying to read into R.

The first table (Citation) has 213 records x 47 fields. When I try to access the dataset in r, it throws a memory allocation error:

```
> library(RODBC)
> db <- "state.mdb"
> qry <- "SELECT * FROM Citation"
> con2 <- odbcConnect("StateDB")
> tbl <- sqlQuery(con2, qry)

Error in odbcQuery(channel, query, rows_at_time) : 
  'Calloc' could not allocate memory (107374182400 of 1 bytes)
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In odbcQuery(channel, query, rows_at_time) :
  Reached total allocation of 10000Mb: see help(memory.size)
```

Yet in the same database, a much larger table called Collision (298,645 records x 40 fields) doesn't throw any kind of error and displays perfectly in R.

What gives?

I've tried the following:

-Increasing the memory available to R from 8055 to 10,000 using memory.limit(size=1000)

-Increasing the amount of RAM in my computer to 8 gb

-Changing my R version to 32-bit (this gave me an 'ODBC Connection Failed' message so I switched back to 64-bit)

You would think the bigger table would be throw the memory error, not the smaller table, so I'm wondering if something else is going on. Especially because the amount of memory it seems to require is very large (107374182400 bytes??)

I'm relatively new to R, so any help would be very much appreciated. I'm using Windows 7 and RStudio, both 64-bit, with 8 GB of RAM.

Comment: If possible, try opening the database in Access and performing a "Compact and Repair Database" operation on it. I agree that the amount of memory being consumed is suspiciously large.

Comment: Nope, still throwing the error. Sorry!

Comment: What happens if you try `SELECT JustOneField FROM Citation`?

Comment: It works fine. I also tried `SELECT [first 5 fields] FROM Citation` and they all displayed correctly. It's happening now with other tables in the same database as well (although some others are working fine) but none of the broken tables share a common denominator. I guess I could just type the fields out manually if I have to, but there's a lot of fields...

Comment: Are there any Memo or OLE Object fields involved?

Comment: Aha! All of the problem tables have OLE fields. When I removed that field, R was able to read it. It's going to be a huge pain going through each table and deleting the OLE fields individually, but at least it was an easy fix. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently RODBC doesn't like OLE Object fields in Access tables. Removing them (or perhaps just omitting them from the columns list of a SELECT statement) seems to avoid the issue.